# How do I validate IAP in android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, in-app-purchase

I am finding it hard to find complete documentation online. So, atm I have a Cloud Firestore DB. A one Non-Consumable that unlocks a premium version. The [short guide](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_best_practices) I did find recommends:

To validate purchase details on a trusted server, complete the following steps:

- Ensure that the device-server handshake is secure.
- Check the returned data signature and the orderId, and verify that the orderId is a unique value that you have not previously processed.
- Verify that your app's key has signed the INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA that you process.
- Validate purchase responses using the ProductPurchase resource (for in-app products) or the SubscriptionPurchase resource (for subscriptions) from the Google Play Developer API. This step is particularly useful because attackers cannot create mock responses to your Play Store purchase requests.

What server do I use? Is cloud fire-store sufficient to complete this validation?

How do I *Verify that your app's key has signed the INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA that you process*

Do I need to read every order ID every time a user makes a purchase? Couldn't this lead to thousands of reads on the DB very quickly?

Here is the `onPurchasesUpdated` code block where I am going to implement the validation:

```
 @Override
public void onPurchasesUpdated(BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) {
    if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingResponseCode.OK
            && purchases != null) {
        int index = 0;
        for (Purchase purchase : purchases) {
            if(purchase.getSignature().equals( /*Somehow check igned the INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA HERE?*/) || purchase.getOrderId().equals(purchases.get(index).getOrderId())) {
                //Invalid
                getMessage("Invalid. Order cancelled");
                return;
            } else {

                handlePurchase(purchase);
            }

        }
    } else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED) {
        getMessage("Payment Cancelled");
    } else {
        getMessage("Error. Try Again");
    }
}
```

What steps should I take? What do you do to validate IAP's? 
Why is the doumentation very poor on this.

Is it even worth the effort? I don't expect this app to vbe downloaded millions of times. Should I just skip it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Firebase Cloud Function for receipt validation. You'd set up an [HTTP triggered](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) function that you pass the purchase token and have it return if the token is valid or not.

You don't *need* to store anything in your database (although you may want to). The receipt validation can be done in a function - and there are some well documented [open-source examples](https://github.com/voltrue2/in-app-purchase) of this online.

Is it worth the effort? That depends on how much time you wish to invest, and whether you think the cost of users with "fake" purchase tokens outweighs this investment.

Another alternative is to use a hosted solution for your in-app purchase server such as [RevenueCat](https://www.revenuecat.com/) (Disclaimer: I work there).

Comment: thanks for the reply. I will look into this when I get the chance.

Comment: @enc_life I am trying to utilize the above open-source lib for Android validation, but I am not understanding the configuration requirements for Google validation. Do you have an example that you might be able to share?